# Why is the IF condition being evaluated to True all the time

Tags: python, algorithm, if-statement

Why the if statement being evaluated to `True` each time, even if I am deliberately giving biased inputs to my code . Here is my code:

```
s1 = 'efgh'
s2 = 'abcd'

for i in range(0, len(s1)):
    for j in range(1, len(s1)+1):
        if s1[i:j] in s2:
            print('YES')
```

It print `YES`, 6 times. Why is that?

Comment: what is your desired output ?

Comment: You could try adding `print(s1[i:j], s2)` inside your loops to see what they are. You're checking empty strings for the `s1` slice.

Comment: An empty string is a substring of every string.

Answer (score 5):

Whenever you have `i >= j`, you will get an empty string for `s1[i:j]`. An empty string always returns `True` when checking `in` another string, hence your print statements.

Instead you should start `j` as `i + 1`:

```
s1 = 'efgh'
s2 = 'abcd'

for i in range(0,len(s1)):
    for j in range(i + 1,len(s1)+1):
        if s1[i:j] in s2:
            print('YES')
```

Which gives no output.

---

> Empty strings are always considered to be a substring of any other string, so "" in "abc" will return True.

[Docs source](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html)

Answer (score 3):

Because some combinations produce the empty string:

```py
s1 = 'efgh'
s2 = 'abcd'

for i in range(0, len(s1)):
    for j in range(1, len(s1) + 1):
        if s1[i:j] in s2:
            print('YES', i, j, repr(s1[i:j]))
```

Output:

```
YES 1 1 ''
YES 2 1 ''
YES 2 2 ''
YES 3 1 ''
YES 3 2 ''
YES 3 3 ''
```

It can also be helpful to see all cases - there are plenty of times when the if condition doesn't pass:

```py
s1 = 'efgh'
s2 = 'abcd'

for i in range(0, len(s1)):
    for j in range(1, len(s1) + 1):
        print(s1[i:j] in s2, i, j, repr(s1[i:j]))
```

Output:

```
False 0 1 'e'
False 0 2 'ef'
False 0 3 'efg'
False 0 4 'efgh'
True 1 1 ''
False 1 2 'f'
False 1 3 'fg'
False 1 4 'fgh'
True 2 1 ''
True 2 2 ''
False 2 3 'g'
False 2 4 'gh'
True 3 1 ''
True 3 2 ''
True 3 3 ''
False 3 4 'h'
```

Answer (score 0):

The `IF` condition is not being evaluated to `True`, all the time. This happens because in some of your loops, `i >= j`. And when this happens, `s1[i:j]` would return an empty string as ''.

In your `if condition`, you check whether, `s1[i:j]` is contained in `s2`. According the above scenario, you will be checking whether `s1[i:j]` (which is an empty String), is contained in `s2`.

By default, every String has an empty string in it. This is like checking the following,

```
if '' in s2: # this is always true
```

According to your code `s1` does not contain any characters, that is also contained in `s2`. Hence, this would only happen when `i >= j`.